# How do I generate dynamic meta description and image in React using React Helmet when both Front End and Backend Nestjs deployed at different servers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nestjs

My backend is built in nestjs and both Front end and Backend is deployed at different servers. It has blog post so whenever I share particular blog(using react-share), It displays default meta description and image which is inside index.html file. I have used React Helmet for dynamic meta tags but is doesn't seem to be working. No matter what I share, It is displaying default meta and when I remove that from index.html file it displays nothing. I have checked from https://heymeta.com . Here is sample of code for :

```
<Helmet>
<title>{singlePost.blogTitle}</title>
<link rel="canonical" href={window.location.href} />
<meta property="og:url" content={window.location.href} />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />

<meta name="twitter:card" content={singlePost.publicImg.asset.url} />

//for Title
<meta property="og:title" content={singlePost.blogTitle} />
<meta itemprop="name" content={singlePost.blogTitle} />
<meta name="twitter:title" content={singlePost.blogTitle}/>

//for Description
<meta property="og:description" content={singlePost.blogDescription} />
<meta itemprop="description" content={singlePost.blogDescription} />
<meta name="twitter:description" content={singlePost.blogDescription} />

//for Image
<meta property="og:image" content={singlePost.publicImg.asset.url} />
<meta itemprop="image" content={singlePost.publicImg.asset.url} />
<meta name="twitter:image" content={singlePost.publicImg.asset.url} />
</Helmet>
```

i am searching for solution to show my shared blog image,title,content dynamically instead of default

Answer (score 0):

In the ReactJS application, you can not set meta tags dynamically in the index.html file. Because ReactJS follows the client side rendering only. So if you are trying to set meta tags using react-helmet. Then it will be changed only in the client (browser) side, not really in the Source code of the index.html file.
So, its a reason you got the default meta tags.

- If you want it. Then you have to create a backend server which serve
  the build of your React application and create every route in the
  backend server and in that each route you have to make an apicall to
  your original backend, which has the data for your meta tags.
- Using that meta tags perform a file operation to the index.html file which replace the predefined attributes with that meta tag
- Then send the updated file in the response.
- So whenever user try to share your blog or specific page of your react application then it's got the meta tags respectively to the pages
- Refernce link: https://dillionmegida.com/p/how-to-configure-meta-tags-in-react-app-dynamically/

Comment: it's useful for me, thanks for response